# multiple conditions with if

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm trying to check that two conditions are fulfilled with an `if...and` statement:

```
if foo < 0 and bar < 0:
    #do something
```

but it's always returning positive. Why?

Here is the complete code:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    t = raw_input("Please enter a number.")
    d = raw_input("Please enter another number")
    limit = raw_input("Please enter another number")
    try:
        t = int(t)
        d = int(d)
        limit = int(limit)
        loop = 0
    except ValueError:
        print "Sorry, but one of those was an invalid input. Please ensure you enter only numbers greater than zero."
    if t > 0 and d > 0:
        loop = 0
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the value that you have in `foo` and `bar`? 
Working example:

```
a = 'True' 
b = 'True'

if (a and b):
    print('Both True')

c = 'Hello'
d = 'Hello'

if (c == d):
    print('Equal')
```

Comment: The actual code is "if t > 0 and d > 0:" It's for data validation.

Comment: Your code seems to be valid.What happens if you put `print(t)` and `print(d)` before your `if statement`? Maybe the values are not what you expect?

Comment: They're user inputs; the code should be able to handle any number. I've done as you suggested, and they're not changing from the input to this piece of code.

Comment: Could you post the complete code? Where t and d are comming from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93240/discussion-between-jay-and-tenzin).

Comment: Don't think I can help, I don't have your Python version, I have Python 3. And it seems things work a bit different with `raw_input`. I do can give you the suggestion what you can also use `while True` and not `while loop == 1`. Then to break the loop use `break` and not `loop = 0`.